# Identify 2 highest scorers and handle the possibility of a draw

Tags: python, oop

I have 5 instances of the `Player` class, and code that simulates games between each of the players. After each game, the time each player took in the game, and their score (2 for a win, 1 for a draw) are stored in `self.totaltime` and `self.score`. After all games are played I am trying to select the two highest scorers out of the players so they can play best out of 3 to decide a winner. It's highly likely more than 1 player has the same score. If this is the case, whoever has taken less time will be selected.

My problem is that I'm having trouble sorting/comparing these results to each other, and I'm really not sure which approach is best to select the 2 highest scoring players. I have tried a for loop (shown below) but I wasn't really thinking properly and of course this doesn't work.

```py
def findPlayers():
    scorers = []
    for player in players:
        for player2 in players:
            if player.score > player2.score:
                scorers.append([player.name, player.score, player.totaltime])
```

I'm sure I sound a fool but I just need nudging in the right direction with this. I have written the bulk of the code for this program, but I seem to be getting stuck on trivial things like this. Regardless, any nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you sort the list and take the first 2?

Comment: Because of the high likelihood that some players will have identical scores - in which case the player with the lowest value in `self.totaltime` will be selected

Comment: So sort them on (score, -totaltime).

Comment: Could you elaborate please? I'm new to sorting in Python in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the list of players using `(self.score, -self.totaltime)` as the key.

```
sorted_players = sorted(players, lambda player: (player.score, -player.totaltime), reverse=True)
```

Comment: OP wants the *highest* score with the *least* totaltime.

Comment: Updated the answer to take negative total time as the key.

Comment: Thanks CaptainDaVinci for the help. I think I need to learn a little more about sorting for the future!